# How to record data from rostopics using MongoDB

Tags: ros, jackal, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have installed the mongodb_store package on my jackal clearpath robot (Ubuntu 14.04) running ros-indigo, and I have started the mongoldb_server by running the commands:

```
rosparam set mongodb_port 62345
rosparam set mongodb_host car-j100-0101
rosrun mongodb_store mongodb_server.py
```

and in the terminal I get a message saying: "[INFO] [WallTime:...] The Aug 2 08:40:27.317 [initandlisten] waiting for connections on port 62345" and nothing else happens after this. Ideally I want to use mongodb_store to store the data that is being published on all of the rostopics on my jackal.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/299434/how-to-record-data-from-rostopics-using-mongodb/) by [dkrivet](https://answers.ros.org/users/36368/dkrivet/) on ROS Answers with karma: 19 on 2018-08-02

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If `mongodb_store` is the package documented at [wiki/mongodb_store](http://wiki.ros.org/mongodb_store), I believe the sections 4, 5 and further document the usage.

Do the example command lines not work for you?

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2018-08-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dkrivet](https://answers.ros.org/users/36368/dkrivet/) on 2018-08-02**:
I tried install mongodb_log from GitHub then using make but it didn't work. Am i able to install through apt-get install ros-indigo-mongodb-log?

**Comment by [dkrivet](https://answers.ros.org/users/36368/dkrivet/) on 2018-08-02**:
So i have installed mongodb_log by doing: `sudo apt-get install ros-indigo-mongodb-log` but when I run the command `rosrn mongodb_log mongodb_log -a` as it states on the wiki I get an error saying "Found the following, but they're either not files, or not executable: /opt/ros/indigo/share/mongodb_lg

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-08-02**:
I've not used this myself, but I believe the script's name is `mongodb_log.py`. Not `mongodb_log`. I know the latter is what the wiki states, but installing the pkg and checking myself I only see a `mongodb_log.py`.